# Updating other item in the custom publish pipeline not working

Tags: publishing, pipelines

I am trying to update an item inside `custom publish pipeline` in `Sitecore 10.2`. It does get updated once but if pipeline runs again the item is not updated.

The item update code gets executed every time but it doesn't update the field every time. Only after the apppool reset it does it once and nothing after that even if the code is executed.

Below is my pipeline code:

```
public class CustomCacheUpdatePublishPipeline
    {
        public void UpdatePublishingDate(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            var sitecoreArgs = args as Sitecore.Events.SitecoreEventArgs;
            if (sitecoreArgs == null)
                return;
            var publisher = sitecoreArgs.Parameters[0] as Publisher;
            if (publisher == null)    
                return;
            var db = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
            Item item  = publisher.Options.RootItem;
            Item configurationItem = db.GetItem(Templates.CarAdvisoryConfiguration.ItemId);
            if (item != null && configurationItem != null)
            {
                ID[] templateIds = configurationItem[Templates.CarAdvisoryConfiguration.Fields.TemplateIds]?.Split('|')?.Select(x => new ID(x))?.ToArray();
                if ((templateIds?.Any() ?? false) &&
                        templateIds.Contains(item.TemplateID) || (item.Axes?.GetAncestors()?.Where(x => templateIds.Contains(x.TemplateID))?.Any() ?? false))
                {
                    using (new EditContext(configurationItem, false /*updateStatistics*/, true /*silent*/))
                    {
                        configurationItem.Fields[Templates.CarAdvisoryConfiguration.Fields.LastUpdated].Value = DateUtil.ToIsoDate(System.DateTime.Now); //this only get updated once and doesn't get updated after say 2 mins
                    }
                    Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
                    Database web = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");

                    Sitecore.Publishing.PublishOptions publishOptions = new Sitecore.Publishing.PublishOptions(master,
                                   web,
                                   Sitecore.Publishing.PublishMode.SingleItem,
                                   configurationItem.Language,
                                   System.DateTime.Now);

                    Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher publisher1 = new Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher(publishOptions);

                    publisher1.Options.RootItem = configurationItem;

                    publisher1.Options.Deep = true;

                    publisher1.Publish();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**config:**

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <events>
            <event name="publish:end">
                <handler type="RACQ.Feature.CarAdvisory.Pipelines.CustomCacheUpdatePublishPipeline, RACQ.Feature.CarAdvisory" method="UpdatePublishingDate" />
            </event>
        </events>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I just want to say that it never ends well when you try to edit a value in a field during publishing. You are better off creating a proper process to indicate the desired DateTime of that Sitecore item, either at the item creation / update, or at the time of approval in workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line

```
using (new EditContext(configurationItem, false /*updateStatistics*/, true /*silent*/))
```

You use `true` for `silent` which means that no events should be triggered. That also means that Sitecore will not clear its caches.

And btw, `EditContext` is obsolete. Just use

```
item.Editing.BeginEdit()
...
item.Editing.EndEdit()
```

Comment: setting silent to false and update statistics to true does the trick.